# NodaTime ZonedDateTime not considering clocks going forward

Tags: c#, nodatime

From Jon Skeet's NodaTime [documentation](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/arithmetic.html):

> The time that we add is effectively "experienced" time - as if we'd
>   simply waited twenty minutes. However, at 1am on that day, the clocks
>   in the Europe/London time zone go forward by an hour - so we end up
>   with a local time of 2:05am, not the 1:05am you might have expected

However, when I try this code, effectively copying and pasting most of it from NodaCode documentation into the application, the `after` variable has *01:05:00*, instead of *02:05:00*. Why isn't it accounting for the time zone?

```
DateTimeZone london = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
LocalDateTime local = new LocalDateTime(2012, 3, 27, 0, 45, 00);
ZonedDateTime before = london.AtStrictly(local);
ZonedDateTime after = before + Duration.FromMinutes(20);

Debug.WriteLine("local = {0}",local);
Debug.WriteLine("before adding 20 minutes = {0}", before);
Debug.WriteLine("after adding 20 minutes= {0}", after);
```

**Output:**

```
local = 03/27/2012 00:45:00
before adding 20 minutes = 2012-03-27T00:45:00 Europe/London (+01)
after adding 20 minutes= 2012-03-27T01:05:00 Europe/London (+01)
```

**Update:**

based on Dean Ward's answer below I tried with 26th instead , still it doesn't realize daylight saving change. :(

```
        DateTimeZone london = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
        LocalDateTime local = new LocalDateTime(2012, 3, 26, 0, 45, 00);
        ZonedDateTime before = london.AtStrictly(local);
        ZonedDateTime after = before + Duration.FromMinutes(20);
```

output:

```
local = 03/26/2012 00:45:00
before adding 20 minutes = 2012-03-26T00:45:00 Europe/London (+01)
after adding 20 minutes= 2012-03-26T01:05:00 Europe/London (+01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DST in Europe/London in 2012 changed on [2012-03-25](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2012). Try changing your initial value to that date...

Comment: I'm afraid its still the same , trying with that date. I'll post the updated code above in a min

Comment: Try 25th instead. Note the output has +01 for your initial date so it thinks it's already in DST.

Comment: Ah..that's right... now it shows 2:05 ... thanks... The documentation says 27 in the link, guess that needs to be fixed. :)

Comment: @user113981: Thanks - will fix that now.

Comment: Thats impressive Jon. 1 hr bug turnaround.  May all software produces be as good. you can big business 25% maintenance and be worse off ;-)